# Selenium how to handle SAP loading icon

Tags: selenium-webdriver, wait

I am automating one SAP web based application and when i am clicking on button, it is not loading whole web page but displaying loading icon.
i inserted explicit wait but i want a more tuned solution for this.i have also attached image for further reference.
[image]

please tell me how can i handle this loading icon.

Comment: You can identify the loading element first and then use webdriver wait to disappear the element ( disappear the element means the page load complete).

Comment: I tried invisibilityofwebelement in expected conditions but it is bot working properly.